# How to trace channel fields when there is a relationship?

Tags: channel-entries, database

I need to write a custom query against the `exp_channel_data` table. However, one of the channel's field is a relationship field. How do I track that back to the appropriate column in the `exp_channel_data`?

I've looked in the `exp_channel_fields` table and found the relationship's `field_id` (say it's 10). However, when I look `exp_channel_data`.`field_id_10`, I just see some number in it. I was hoping it would give me the entry id of the row it's related to. Any ideas how to do this? I'm trying to do a JOIN based on the entry id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number that you are seeing in field_id is the `rel_id` from the `exp_relationships` table in that table you have access to the child and parent id's so that you can build your query.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM exp_channel_data 
INNER JOIN 
exp_channel_titles 
ON 
exp_channel_title.entry_id = exp:channel_data.entry_id
```

To get the join right for the two main tables, but what kind of information do you need exactly from the relationship field?